# How do I add a context node to an xpath query in puppeteer?

Tags: node.js, xpath, puppeteer

I'm trying to loop through several elements on a page and get some data in each div....however it doesn't look like xpath`page.$x(<query>)` supports a context node. Either that or I'm not specifying the context node correctly:

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

async function scrape(url) {
  console.log('scraping', url);
  const res = [];
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.goto(url);

  const deals = await page.$x('//*[@class="a-row dealContainer dealTile"]/div/div[2]/div');
  // const dealEls = await page.evaluate((...deals) => {
  //   return deals.map(el => el);
  // }, ...deals);

  console.log(deals.length, 'found');

  for (let deal of deals) {
    const [imgEl] = await deal.$x('//*[@id="dealImage"]/div/div/div[1]/img');
    const src = await imgEl.getProperty('src');
    const img = await src.jsonValue();

    const [titleEl] = await deal.$x('//*[@id="dealTitle"]/span');
    const text = await titleEl.getProperty('textContent');
    const title = await text.jsonValue();

    const [priceEl] = await deal.$x('//*[@id="101_dealView_0"]/div/div[2]/div/div/div[3]/div[1]/span');
    const priceTxt = await priceEl.getProperty('textContent');
    const price = await priceTxt.jsonValue();

    //
    const [origPriceEl] = await deal.$x('//*[@id="101_dealView_0"]/div/div[2]/div/div/div[3]/div[2]/span[2]');
    const origTxt = await origPriceEl.getProperty('textContent');
    const origPrice = await origTxt.jsonValue();

    res.push({img, title: title.trim(), price, origPrice});
  }


  await browser.close();
  console.log(res);
}

scrape('https://www.amazon.com/gp/goldbox/ref=gbps_ftr_s-5_111b_prm_ISPM?gb_f_deals1=dealTypes:DEAL_OF_THE_DAY%252CBEST_DEAL%252CLIGHTNING_DEAL,sortOrder:BY_SCORE,dealStates:AVAILABLE%252CWAITLIST%252CWAITLISTFULL,includedAccessTypes:GIVEAWAY_DEAL,enforcedCategories:172282,discountRanges:10-25%252C25-50%252C50-70,minRating:3,primeEligibleOnly:true&pf_rd_p=18c48e87-0e4c-4250-8975-2c9a7587111b&pf_rd_s=slot-5&pf_rd_t=701&pf_rd_i=gb_main&pf_rd_m=ATVPDKIKX0DER&pf_rd_r=8A7XXQ3N68HFWAMNKHZF&ie=UTF8')
```

Answer (score 3):

To search inside of another node, you can use [`elementHandle.$x`](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/v3.0.1/docs/api.md#elementhandlexexpression) instead of [`page.$x`](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/v3.0.1/docs/api.md#pagexexpression). Quote from the docs:

> The method evaluates the XPath expression relative to the elementHandle.

In addition, you need to change the `//*` to `/*` as `//*` queries all nodes from the root of the document instead of using the node given.

**Code Sample**

That means, the corresponding part of the code should look like this:

```js
const imgEl = await deal.$x('/*[@id="dealImage"]/div/div/div[1]/img');
```

Comment: When I do this it appears to be searching entire doc. I only ever get the first element. I have updated OP

Comment: @chovy It seems you need to change `//` to `/`.

Comment: I get undefined for imgEl

Comment: even doing '/*img' fails